# Django importing text file Data Into sqllit3

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models

I have tabulated text files of my data and records are too much in number i cant upload it one by one in database 
is there any way to import that data into the table i created in model

Comment: Hey Yousaf, welcome to SO! Can you be more specific, do you want to import a files content into a database or is a multiple object, new line separated structure in your file?

Comment: I have text file separated with /t and every row is a new record i want to import that record into database so i can set query for that record

Comment: Okay, so you have different options how to handle it, either you handle it through requests, so you will need some kind of [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#filefield), or you manage it through the command line, so you need a [python script](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to handle it.

Comment: how can i do it using python script like we do load data infile in mysql

Comment: easiest thing would be to convert your file into .csv format and import it using https://pypi.org/project/django-csvimport/

Comment: write a python script to open the text file as csv with seperator '\t' and insert it in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a simple script that might be a start for you. This script will read in a csv-file and store it into a database. You should be able to modify it to meet your needs by replacing `filename.csv` to the location of your file, and `YourModel` to the actual model that it represents. You will also need to change `obj.field1 = line[0]` to the representing columns and fields that are matched with each other.

```py
import csv

# Open the csv file and reads it into a two dimensional List
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    lines = list(reader)

# Create an empty list of objects of your model
objects = []

# Iterate each record of the csv file
for line in lines:
    # Create an empty instance of your model
    obj = YourModel()
    # Populate the fields of the model based on the record line of your file
    obj.field1 = line[0] # The first column
    obj.field2 = line[1] # The second column
    # Add the model to the list of objects
    objects.append(obj)

# Save all objects simultaniously, instead of saving for each line
YourModel.objects.bulk_create(objects)
```